Issue with Pages Not Getting Indexed Because Google Selected Canonical of a Completely Different Web Page
We're encountering an issue where Google is not indexing some of our pages, and the Search Console provides the following reason:
"Page is not indexed: Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user."
URL not indexed: https://www.qdesq.com/virtual-office/mumbai
URL indexed (Google's chosen canonical): https://www.qdesq.com/meeting-rooms/mumbai
Screenshot of search console : search console screenshot

This issue is affecting our site across the board, specifically with URLs in the format: https://www.qdesq.com/virtual-office/{cityName}. The URLs that Google selects as canonical are in the format: https://www.qdesq.com/meeting-rooms/{cityName}.
Previously, the structure of the webpages for both URL formats was the same. We updated the entire structure of the pages three days ago, but the Search Console is still showing the same error.
Not able to understand why is google selecting the completely different HTML as canonical.

Are you saying that you only updated the canonical structure 3 days ago?  If so, I'd just give Google a bit longer to see if it remains a problem when it is all fully crawled and re-indexed.
Otherwise, one potential reason is that you're linking to the non-canonical page in your sitemap.

I have updated the webite structure of /virtual-office page 3 days back and on search console its showing getting crawled today. Can you please elaborate on "Otherwise, one potential reason is that you're linking to the non-canonical page in your sitemap"

(RE: sitemap - sorry, I'd misread your problem, and so that's not a valid point)
